# Как с помощью модуля os получить название диска, в котором находится текущий каталог?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Пожалуйста, подскажите, есть ли оптимальный способ извлечения названия диска, в котором находится текущий каталог? Или легче обрезать путь к текущему каталогу после первого слэша?

Comment: попробуйте `os.getcwd()`

Comment: `pathlib.Path().absolute().drive`

Comment: @finally, к сожалению, так я получаю полный путь к каталогу

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
a =os.getcwd()
b =a[0]+a[1]+a[2]
```

Comment: почему не `a[:3]` ?

Comment: Пожалуйста комментируйте ответы. Тем более это не очень удачный вариант. Ваш ответ зависит от операционной системы. В не-Windows будет получен некорректный результат